# ASP.NET C# write value in text box to a label: beginner simple

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, document.write

I am trying to find a very simple example for the syntax to simple write the value entered into a text box, and place that value into a label onclick. As basic as it can get I suppose. I only mentioned asp.net because I would like to do that with an aspx page. Thanks!

Comment: How about JQuery  $('label').val = $('textBox').val

Or something like this... this is just some JQ pseudo code

Comment: In Visual Web Developer, create an empty web project, add a web form, drag a button, label and textbox onto the web form from the toolbox, double click on the button, type in `the name of the label.Text` - `=` - `Name of the textbox.Text` then add a semicolon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and in the cs file

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Label` does not have a server `OnClick` event.

You could use a Button:

```
void [ButtonID]_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
   [LabelID].Text = [TextBoxID].Text; 
}
```

Replace the values inside square brackets with the real IDs.

Or you could use Javascript, but that's another story! :)

Answer (score 1):

The page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server">Hello World</asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="MyBtn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="MyBtn_Clicked" />
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
   using System;

   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       protected void MyBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {
           this.MyLabel.Text = this.MyTextBox.Text;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
   using System;

   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

       protected void MyBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {
           this.MyLabel.Text = this.MyTextBox.Text;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class CodeBehind : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much you can just use similar type labels like the ones seen above.